# Java code for connect alfresco through ftps connection

Tags: java, alfresco, ftp-client, ftps

When I try to connect our alfresco through SFTP it is not able to connect alfresco. It hangs the explorer and no error goes in the logger file also.

```
public void FTPTest()throws SocketException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{

    FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient("SSL");
    System.out.println("1");
    ftp.connect("172.17.178.144",2121); // or "localhost" in your case
    System.out.println("2"+ftp.getReplyString());

    System.out.println("login: "+ftp.login("admin", "admin"));
    System.out.println("3"+ ftp.getReplyString());
    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/alfresco");
    // list the files of the current directory
    FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Listed "+files.length+" files.");
    for(FTPFile file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
    // lets pretend there is a JPEG image in the present folder that we want to copy to the desktop (on a windows machine)
    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // don't forget to change to binary mode! or you will have a scrambled image!
    FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\casonkl\\Desktop\\my_downloaded_image_new_name.jpg");

    ftp.retrieveFile("name_of_image_on_server.jpg", br);
    ftp.disconnect();

}
```

I got output in our console only
 1
at the execution of ftp.connect("172.17.178.144",2121); this code system will be hang no error got in our console

I am able to connect to my Alfresco through SFTP with the Filezila FTP client software. Can any one help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken then Alfresco chose for FTPS.

So try it with the following code here: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-net-2.2/src/main/java/examples/ftp/FTPSExample.java.shtml

Comment: Thank u malik for sharing the code but when I m impleneting this code getting error could not  connect to server org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.          can u help me why I m getting this error  my code is following

Comment: Have you tried it first without the FTPSClient and just FTP Client?

Comment: yes I m able to connect our server with filezila ftp client through ftps . and from java  code alos I m able to connect our server through ftp  any changes or setting need on server ya local machine for FTPS